# Ubuntu 21.10 installer thinks my boot partition is corrupted

Tags: boot, dual-boot, boot-partition

Ubuntu 21.10 installation getting stuck at the screen where it asks for third party software and updates to be downloaded. It hangs forever.
I am trying to install it alongside Windows 10.

After a few tries, I decided to open Gparted, and I saw red Xs on the boot partition (fat) and the little partition next to it (16 Mib).

This system boots without issue into Windows, and, until I deleted them, into a few linux distros as well (the latter via grub).

Because I was unable to install Ubuntu, I ran the installer of a different distro (debian-based) and it installed successfully, and boots successfully as well, so I question the "wisdom" of Gparted regarding my "corrupted" boot partition...

But the real question is what to do about this, besides deleting the boot partition and thereby forfeiting my Windows boot.

Comment: Typically the red X means an issue. But not always valid. The Microsoft reserved is an unformatted but required by Windows partition. Since unformatted it is shown as an error. Errors on the ESP - efi system partition can be from having Windows fast start up on, having settings in UEFI protecting ESP writes (some type of security setting) or corruption that a dosfsck would fix.

Comment: So maybe I should try dosfsck, then, if disabling fast startup and secure boot doesn't do it. Thanks for the ideas. I know that Ubuntu can boot with those two settings enabled, but maybe it doesn't install so well that way.